# What is the volatile keyword purpose in c#?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I want to see the real time use of `Volatile` keyword in c#. but am unable to project the best example. the below sample code works without `Volatile` keyword how can it possible?

```
class Program
{
    private static int a = 0, b = 0;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Thread t1 = new Thread(Method1);
        Thread t2 = new Thread(Method2);

        t1.Start();
        t2.Start();

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static void Method1()
    {
        a = 5;
        b = 1;
    }

    static void Method2()
    {
        if (b == 1)
            Console.WriteLine(a);
    }
}
```

In the above code i am getting a value as 5. how it works without using volatile keyword?

Comment: It doesn't work. Since you forgot to use `volatile`, you expect to get some value other than 5. Yet you get 5. So it's *not* working, which is what you would expect for leaving something out. (Fix the bug and the mystery will go away. Code with threading bugs is almost impossible to understand. Just fix them and forget about it.)

Comment: Can you tell me one best example for volatile?

Comment: Now, without any `volatile` keyword, there's no **guarantee** that the program will not output `0`. It might (some day) output `0`. If you add the `volatile` keyword, it can't output `0`, it can only give _either_ no output _or_ `5`.

Comment: @yug If you look in the [C# Language Specification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228593.aspx), the section **Volatile fields**, there's a "one best example" that looks a lot like your own example.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `volatile` keyword tells the compiler that a variable can change at any time, so it shouldn't optimise away reading and writing of the variable.

Consider code like this:

```
int sum;
for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
  sum += x * i;
}
```

As the variable `x` doesn't change inside the loop, the compiler might read the variable once outside the loop and just use the same value throughout the loop.

If you make the variable `x` volatile, the compiler will read the value of the variable each time that it is used, so if you change the value in a different thread, the new value will be used immediately.

Answer (score 2):

If you use `volatile` properly, your code is guaranteed to work. If you leave out `volatile` where your code requires it, it will probably work fine most of the time, but it is not guaranteed and will probably fail when it will hurt the most.

Understanding how code with threading races fails or doesn't fail requires a deep understanding of the implementation and the platform. It's not simple and usually not worth worrying about. Just follow the rules and your code will work all the time.